# framework not found RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I was installing Realm and imported to my project but when I run the app it shows me an error:

> ld: framework not found RealmSwift
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you installing via the Cocoapods app and can you include your podfile in the question so we can take a look?

Comment: yes i use cocapods and installed succefully but cant import to my project

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this issue.

To get the exact issue you can follow the below step :

Right click on error and select 'Reveal in log'. This will give you more insight about the reason of error.

[image]

One of the solution is to setting the 'Enabled Bitcode' to No. For this go to Build settings in your target and search 'Bitcode' in the search field.

I have faced this issue multiple times and one of the below solution may work for you.

- After installing the pods make sure that you're opening the workspace instead of Xcode project file.
- Restart Xcode
- Remove derive data for your application
- Reintegrate pods using `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` for your project
- Reset simulator(If you are viewing the output in simulator)
- Ensure proper linking of Framework in your project
- Restart simulator
- Clean project etc.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Are you using the RealmSwift from the Cocoa pods? If yes are other cocoa pods working fine for you?

Comment: Yes i use Cocoa pods and other framework work fine but not for **Realm**

Comment: I just installed the RealmSwift with Xcode 10.1 and it is working fine. I suggest that you first remove the RealmSwift from pods then install the pods. After installation again add the RealmSwift(latest version) to the pods and install again. This might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

Initially, I was trying to import the files (Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework) from download folder but then i was getting the same error like yours.

What i did then, i copied the folder containing the (Realm.framework and RealmSwift.framework) into the project folder and then i imported the files from there. That resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've updated the Cocopods to the latest version (1.1.0) via this command `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you are still running the .xcodeproj file. You should run `.workspace` file in your xcdoe

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31085978)