# ld: framework not found Realm - installing for Xcode Version 11.3.1, pod RealmSwift 10.1.4

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cocoapods

I am a beginner in iOS development, and my first task is to install `Realm` using CocoaPods. I followed [the guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/install/) but got the following error:

```
ld: framework not found Realm
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My machine:

```
macOS Catalina 10.15.7 
Xcode: Version 11.3.1 (11C505)
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Notes-App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Notes-App
  pod 'RealmSwift', '=10.1.4'

end
```

In `platform :ios, '12.0'` I also tried `4.3` and `9.0`. Same error.
[The troubleshooting guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/troubleshooting/#std-label-ios-resolve-build-issues) didn't help. Same error

Pod version:

```
pod --version
1.10.1
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315467/14351818

Comment: A few things. Update your cocoapods to ensure you have 1.10.1 with this command in terminal `sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`. Then update your podfile to use the latest Realm release `pod 'RealmSwift', '>= 10.0.0'`. Then ensure XCode is completely closed, navigate to your apps folder in terminal and do a `pod update` within the project folder. Oh, and ensure you're opening your project with the `xcworkspace` file, not the `xcodeproj` file. Oh, is that your COMPLETE podfile?

Answer (score 0):

Hy! You should use the white .workspace file after installing the pod file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).